# Javascript a synchronous loop inside a synchronous loop using Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a JavaScript loop

```
            for (var index = 0; index < this.excelData.results.length; index++) { 
            let pmidList = this.excelData.results[index]["PMIDList"];
            if (pmidList.length == 0 ){
            continue;
            }
             let count = 0;
             let pmidsList = pmidList.split(',');
              if (pmidsList.length > 200){
                pmidList = pmidsList.slice(count, count+ 200).join(',');
              } else { 
                pmidList= pmidsList.join(",");
              
               }

             // Create some type of mini loop
              // pmidList  is a comma separated string so I need to first put it into an array           
             // then slice the array into 200 item segments

               let getJSONLink = 'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?'       
               getJSONLink += 'db=pubmed&retmode=json&id=' + pmidList
               await axios.get(getJSONLink)
              .then(res => {  
                let jsonObj = res.data.result;
                   //Do Stuff with the data
                  } 
  
                }).catch(function(error) {
              console.log(error);
          });   
            //Loop
       }
```

the entire process works fine EXCEPT when the PMIDList has more than 200 comma separated items.  The web service only will accept 200 at a time. So I need to add an internal loop that parses out the first 200 hundred and loop back around to do the rest before going to the next index and it would be nice to do this synchronously since the webservice only allows 3 requests a second. And since I'm using Vue wait is another issue.

Comment: Nice to know why it was down graded.  If the person who downgraded it can show me how to do it it would be appreciated.   The major problem is with the wait inside a Vue app.  Standard waits don't work and without the wait the webservice does not work.  I have hired people at Freelancer 3 time to get this to work and it is still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be to use async await within a while loop, mutating the original array. Something like:

```
async function doHttpStuff(params) {
    let getJSONLink = 'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?'       
    getJSONLink += 'db=pubmed&retmode=json&id=' + params.join('')
    return axios.get(getJSONLink)
}
```

and use it inside your inner while loop:

```
...
let pmidsList = pmidList.split(',');
// I'll clone this, because mutating might have some side effects?
const clone = [...pmidsList];
while(clone.length) {
  const tmp = clone.splice(0, 199); // we are mutating the array, so length is reduced
  const data = await doHttpStuff(tmp);
  // do things with data
}
...
```